# How to write the code in easy way python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

This is my code and it was working perfectly. Is there any other way to write the code like this in one function itself(to make code more simpler) for server take list_server, server1 take list_server1, server2 take list_server2 and server3 take list_server3

```
server = ['10.10.1.21','10.10.1.22','10.10.1.23']
server1 = ['10.10.1.51','10.10.1.52','10.10.1.53']
server2 = ['10.10.1.31','10.10.1.32','10.10.1.33']
server3 = ['10.10.1.41','10.10.1.42','10.10.1.43']

list_server = ['java','java1','java2']
list_server1 = ['process','process1']
list_server2 = ['check','check']
list_server3 = ['list','list1']

def func1():
    for hostname in server:
        for i in list_server:
            <my statements>
        else:
             <my statments>

def func2():
    for hostname1 in server1:
        for j in list_server1:
            <my statements>
        else:
             <my statments>

def func3():
    for hostname2 in server2:
        for k in list_server2:
            <my statements>
        else:
             <my statments>

def func4():
    for hostname3 in server3:
        for l in list_server3:
            <my statements>
        else:
             <my statments>

def main():
    func1()
    func2()
    func3()
    func4()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `<my statements>` pair is the same for each function, use an argument to cut the code:

```
def myFunc(s, ls):
    for hostname in s:
        for i in ls:
            <my statements>
        else:
             <my statments>
```

Then, call it with different parameters:

```
def main():
    myFunc(server, list_server)
    myFunc(server1, list_server2)
    myFunc(server2, list_server3)
    myFunc(server3, list_server4)
```